# Mapbox & React: Unable to input values into search box

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I'm using a combination of React/Mapbox (DeckGL more specifically) in a project. I want to include Geocoding for querying addresses.

My current output:

[image]

Generated with this code:

```
<DeckGL {...deckGLProps} ref={deckRef}>
        <StaticMap
          ref={mapRef}
          {...staticMapProps}
        />
        <div style={{ border: '5px solid black', top: 500, display: 'inline-block', zIndex: '9999'}}>
          <Geocoder
            mapRef={mapRef}
            onViewportChange={handleGeocoderViewportChange}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
            position="top-left"
            minLength={1}
            trackProximity={true}
            countries={"us"}
            reverseGeocode={true}
            enableEventLogging={false}
          />
        </div>
      </DeckGL>
```

My problem: I'm unable to click on the search bar. This is shown by the strange positioning of the search bar within its `div`. Is there a way to place the component so that the search bar is clickable? I don't think it's a problem with the `Geocoder` component since the code in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7p179qr6m) example works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the official `react-map-gl-geocoder` [repo](https://github.com/SamSamskies/react-map-gl-geocoder) you can use [`containerRef` prop](https://github.com/SamSamskies/react-map-gl-geocoder#props) in order to place the geocoder outside of the map (or whatever you want, note `position: absolute` css prop):

[Example:](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0m14q5rly)

```
const geocoderContainerRef = useRef();

// render
return (
  <div>
    <div
      ref={this.geocoderContainerRef}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 50,
        left: 50
      }}
    />
    <MapGL
      ref={this.mapRef}
      {...viewport}
      onViewportChange={this.handleViewportChange}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    >
      <Geocoder
        mapRef={this.mapRef}
        containerRef={this.geocoderContainerRef}
        onResult={this.handleOnResult}
        onViewportChange={this.handleGeocoderViewportChange}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      />
      <DeckGL {...viewport} layers={[searchResultLayer]} />
    </MapGL>
  </div>
);
```